# A word to describe feeling less of an emotion

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a verb and also a phrasal verb to describe to gradually feel less of an emotion (anger) over a period of time to the point of almost non-existent?

For example: John was ridiculed by Dave during class, making him want to punch Dave out, but at the time it was inconvenient to do so.  By the time class is over his anger has already ***_*__** and he no longer wanted to give him a beating.

Comment: For this *particular* case I would use "cooled", but that doesn't apply to all emotions.

Comment: I like the informality of it. Is there a phrasal verb that can apply to this?

Comment: After he cooled off, he no longer...
After he cooled down, ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[dissipate](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dissipate): "(with reference to a feeling or emotion) disappear or cause to disappear"

Answer (score 9):

In the context of your example (with some tense changes), especially when referring to anger, I would use "By the time class was over, his anger had already **[subsided](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/subsided)**".

Answer (score 3):

I would say *diminished* or *died out*.

Answer (score 1):

*Dissipated* works for this purpose.  Merriam-Webster defines the word to mean "to cause to spread thin or scatter and gradually vanish."  It's often used in reference to feelings and also to the loss of energy as in "the heat from the car dissipated after parking in the shade" or "his anger dissipated as the situation became clear."

Answer (score 1):

I would say that *[abated](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/abate)* fits here.

Answer (score 0):

Emotional blunting is a phrase commonly used in psychiatric/mental health circles. the phrase is emotional blunting" is used to describe someone who either doesn't show 'appropriate' levels of emotion due to a mental disorder like schizophrenia, or who shows less emotion due to trauma.

Answer (score 0):

Waned, faded, eased, vanished, dissolved, melted away

Any synonym of "faded" should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

I would also consider *ebb*, *eddy*, or *wane*.

Comment: *Ebb* and *wane* are nice, but where do you get *eddy*?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  The usage I'm sugesting here would be simile with the tide..  ?   Are you asking for a literary quote?

Comment: No, I'm asking why you think *eddy* can be used to mean the same as *ebb* and *wane*.  *Eddy* means *to move at variance with the main current in a stream of liquid, especially in a rotary motion*  (modified from [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/eddy)).

Comment: Hmmm, well, I think I may have gotten it from Shakespeare.  Something about the eddy of the tide of somebodies pride... being forced back out to ..  sorry.  It doesn't seem to want to google and I can't remember it.

Comment: Well, it doesn't fit.

Comment: You are most certainly welcome to your opinion on the matter.

Comment: Now that I have a little more time I dug it up for you: it is from Rape of Lucrece.  Frankly, I think Shakespeare outweighs Dictionary.com.  You may chose to disagree.

Comment: But you're misreading it.  It goes *As through an arch the violent roaring tide
Outruns the eye that doth behold his haste;
Yet in the eddy boundeth in his pride
Back to the strait that forced him on so fast;
In rage sent out, recall'd in rage, being past:*.  **Eddy** there doesn't mean *ebb* - it's not even a verb.